# wiring in interior wall

Tags: wiring, house

I needed a few more inches of wire on an existing run that I was putting adding a junction box. The wires are in the attic running down inside interior wall for outlets. I pulled on the wire hoping to get some extra, pulled a little hard at one point and felt/hear like a tearing noise. My question is, do you think it's just the outer sheathing that was stretching/tearing some or could I have pulled the sheathing enough to expose the actual wiring, maybe even wire jacket on the staple that was holding it.
I know I am going to get a hard time for being an idiot, but this is driving me nuts and I don't want to have to cut open a perfectly good wall. By the way, this was done about 8 to 10 yr ago. But every so often it bugs me, and I keep thinking I need to tear the wall open and check it.
Thanks for your support of me being an idiot!
Dean

Comment: 8 to 10 years and the house has not burnt down is a good sign.  An inspection camera would help to check condition of the wires without tearing the walls apart.  An AFCI breaker on that circuit is also good insurance.

Comment: What kind of "wires"? It sounds like you meant to say "cable". A cheap snake camera can easily be sent down a hole from the attic to see what's going on in the wall, which presumably isn't packed full of insulation being an interior wall. As it stands, chances are extremely small of having any kind of dangerous situation.

Comment: kreemoweet - sorry about that it's 14/2 or 16/2 Romex. I am not sure I can get a camera down the hole but i'll look into it as an option.

Comment: crip659 - thanks for the suggestions. You would think if I had bare wires, it would short out on the staple and blow the breaker.

Comment: That is the best out come, but damaged wires do not always trip a breaker.  One reason for GFCI and AFCI protection.